# orderer.common.broadcast ccd Error reading from 10.110.16.204:37291: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I can invoke chaincode successful,but I noticed that the  orderer logs has some warn logs,the detail info are shown in the image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEwRl.png).I want to know why come this warn logs?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEwRl.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's fine.
It means at that specific point, a resource was unreachable.
Probably an orderer / kafka broker. It can happen.

Later on, the resource reconnected and was reachable.
It is just a warning and you will receive it every time two points try to contact each other but cannot do it.